# Concatenate without reducing number of rows Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2oPN.png). Which contains data of every hour for each day in a week for two different weeks.
I'm trying to get average of `totalconsumedenergy` from dataframe1 and dataframe2 by concatenating but without reducing the `day_of_week`.

```
sensors_data_new = pd.concat([df1, df2])
sensors_data = sensors_data_new.groupby(level=0).mean()
```

I've tried this but this also reduces the number of days to 1 per column. I want to keep the number i.e `days_of_week` row as it is just create a new dataframe with an average of `totalconsumedenergy` from both the dataframes.

Comment: maybe first check what you get with `concat()` - maybe you create wrong data and it needs some parameters to create it correctly. You could show example data as text (or better as code with `DataFrame(...)`) and expected result for example data - because I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: if you want mean for every week - then maybe you should first calculate `mean()` for `df1` and `df2` and later concatenate results. OR maybe you should add column `week number` and later group by pair `['week number', 'days_of_week']`